# The Explosive Force of the Braking Alcubierre Drive - What would this look like?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, warp-drives

The Alcubierre Drive and faster than light travel more generally may be locked away in the realm of fiction forever. That might be depressing to some people but I think their impossibility is really interesting in it's own right.

Here is [The Alcubierre Warp Drive: On the Matter of Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5708) (2012). In it the authors state that a functional Alcubierre Warp drive has the capacity to destroy what is in front of it as it brakes (for lack of a better word). In more detail:

> "These results suggest that any ship using an Alcubierre warp drive
> carrying people would need shielding to protect them from potential
> dangerously blueshifted particles during the journey, and any people
> at the destination would be gamma ray and high energy particle blasted
> into oblivion due to the extreme blueshifts for P+ region particles."

The paper goes on to explain that P+ represents particles with initial positive velocity that are overtaken by a superluminal bubble.

I would like to know more about this detonation.

Let's handwave FTL being impossible and say a ship is flying through time and space using an Alcubierre Drive. As it goes: what particles are being captured, how much energy could be expected to be released (a quantitative answer/approximation would be amazing) and what would the emission look like?

Note: Equation 15 of the paper may provide insight to an understanding of the relevant blueshifts, however, the authors later write:

> Technically the particles in the P+ cannot leave the bubble, and so
> there is no value given for this region. However, the time component
> of the 4-velocity the particles in this region increases exponentially
> for the duration of the time they are caught in the bubble. Hence if
> the ship were to ever slow to below the speed of light such that they
> could escape and interact with outside observers, they would be
> observed to have extremely large energies.

Which has confused me to no end.

Comment: should  you not ask this  in a sci-fi  forum? it has nothing to do with physic. https://scifi.stackexchange.com

Comment: You present an interesting point of view, Trula, but let me propose a different one. While the question considers an event whose cause (FTL) is for all intents and purposes impossible, the matter at hand/effect (particle release) should be something we can firmly understand through existing physics, no? Perhaps it's ironic for me to speak of cause and effect with FTL (haha) but I'm not interested in a justification of the impossible, only a physically sound explanation of a hypothetical situation. Note the work cited was by physicists and astronomers who clearly thought it was worth exploring.

Comment: You seem confused on this "warp" drive.  I didn't read the 2012 paper that you linked, but the original paper by Alcubierre provides a solution to the Einstein equations, although one that requires some exotic form of matter to power it.  There's no faster than light travel there as defined by GR. All of this talk about FLT in your question is a distraction and likely to lead people to think you're in SciFi land or alternate theories of relativity (ala comment by @trula). Suggest a revision that focuses the question strictly to mainstream physics to avoid being closed.

Comment: "Alcubierre drive" is perhaps a misleading name. It might be called "an interesting example of what spacetime would do if the stress-energy tensor (i.e. the configuration of matter) could take forms which as far we know are physically impossible, comparable to negative mass and things like that".

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy to see why this happens. A trip in the warp bubble can last an arbitrarily small amount of coordinate time, so let's suppose it lasts less than the light travel time across the bubble. Then look at a right-moving wavefront at the start of the trip that reaches the rightmost interior point of the bubble when the bubble arrives at the destination, and another wavefront at the destination that will be at the rightmost part of the bubble's exterior when the bubble arrives, and a bunch of others in between those in the background space. None of these wavefronts can overtake each other, and the leftmost and rightmost ones are separated by the width of the boundary of the bubble when it arrives, so all of the intermediate ones are crammed into the intermediate space. That translates to an average blueshift factor of roughly the length of the trip (light years, probably) divided by the width of the bubble boundary (who knows, but much smaller). The total energy would probably increase by a similar factor.

I question the relevance of this for a variety of reasons.

First, the warp drive already plows through everything in its path between the starting and ending points, so who cares if it also destroys some stuff past the ending point?

Second, they're simply calculating geodesics in the spacetime, meaning they're assuming that their test particles don't interact nongravitationally with the exotic matter. If the exotic matter is opaque then their conclusion is invalidated. It may as well be opaque since it's made-up stuff anyway.

In fact, since the exotic matter vanishes magically into nowhere when its work is done, we may as well suppose that all of the energy of the particles it absorbs disappears with it. It might seem that this violates energy conservation, but it doesn't matter: you can write down a spacetime geometry where the energy isn't there at the end, and plug it into the GR field equation, and then argue that we would get that spacetime geometry if we could just engineer that stress-energy tensor. It's no different from what Alcubierre did, and no less plausible as far as I can tell.

The fundamental problem is that there are no rules restricting warp drive solutions. You can get a stress-energy tensor from any differentiable metric, so anything you write down is fair game. A real theory of warp drives would require an actual physical theory with exotic matter in it, and would probably look nothing like what Alcubierre wrote down.